# Add New row for a 3D Array in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to add a new row for a 3D array?

Ex: Let's say we have arrays with these dimensions

```
arr1.shape = (1,1,20)
arr2.shape = (1,1,20)

combined.shape = (1,2,20)
```

How can I do this in numpy?

Comment: `np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concatenate` and specify the desired `axis` like the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.ones((1, 1, 20))
arr2 = np.ones((1, 1, 20))

print(np.concatenate((arr1, arr2), axis=1).shape)
```

Alternativly you can use `hstack` like the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.ones((1, 1, 20))
arr2 = np.ones((1, 1, 20))

print(np.hstack((arr1,arr2)).shape)
```